# Unable to connect to wireless after Fedora 28 upgrade

Tags: fedora, wifi

I was running a Fedora 27 machine with no problems. My upgrade to Fedora 29 had several issues, so I decided to upgrade instead to Fedora 28. Everything works great, except I can't connect to wireless.

I've tried:

- the solution discussed [here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1555935) about updating `iwl-wifi`. I also have the latest `linux-firmware` installed.
- the solution discussed [here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1599036) about downgrading `wpa_supplicant`. Unfortunately, the `$ nmcli connection modify  wifi-sec.pmf disable; nmcli connection up` command returns `Error: unknown connection 'wifi-sec.pmf'.`
- rebooting the router.
- rebooting the machine itself.

`lspci` returns

```
1e:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
20:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 6b)
```

`dmesg | grep wifi` returns

```
[   16.531719] iwlwifi 0000:20:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   16.551977] iwlwifi 0000:20:00.0: loaded firmware version 17.3216344376.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[   16.677708] iwlwifi 0000:20:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7260, REV=0x144
[   16.695335] iwlwifi 0000:20:00.0: base HW address: 58:91:cf:17:74:f1
[   16.910285] iwlwifi 0000:20:00.0 wlp32s0: renamed from wlan0
[   83.376356] iwlwifi 0000:20:00.0: No beacon heard and the time event is over already...
[   94.192979] iwlwifi 0000:20:00.0: No beacon heard and the time event is over already...
```

Everything is up to date within the F28 repositories.

Comment: Fill a [bugreport](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_file_a_bug_report).